# Got syntax error on SQL case statement

Tags: sql

```
SELECT 
  name,
  type,
  (case when to_char(expiresdate)>to_char(now()) 
      then active 
   else 
      expired end
  ) as 'membership status', 
  expiresdate    
FROM 
  membership
```

I got an syntax error on this sql but I can't figure out where I did wrong

Comment: what is the error message

Comment: Why are you converting `expiresdate` to char?   Doesn't `now()` return a datetime data type?

Comment: Issue is with condition in case statement, You are comparing char datatype with date.

Comment: @NavneetRabadiya doesn't seem like that should produce a syntax error though.   I would think it would be a conversion error.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that it's from using single quotes for the expression alias.  Try `"membership status"` or `[membership status]`

```
(case when to_char(expiresdate)>(now()) 
then active 
else expired end) 
as [membership status]
```

(Broken into individual lines for better clarity)

An explanation:  the single quotes make `'membership status'` into a string literal.  That can't be used as an alias.  Aliases can be a single word (beginning with a letter), a series of words in double quotes, or a series of words in square brackets.

So all these would work:

```
... as membershipstatus
... as [membership status]
... as "membership status"
```

This may not be the only problem with your SQL statement - others have pointed out that you're doing weird things with dates and strings - but I believe this is why you're getting a syntax error specifically, which is what you asked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
name,
type,
case when to_char(expiresdate)>(now()) 
then active else 
expired end as 'membership status', 
expiresdate    
FROM membership
```